# In Tensorflow, calculatin Spearman instead of accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

How to calculate Spearman and also Pearson correlations instead of the accuracy, for example in the below code chunk?
(For a complete code example, you can also answer over this tutotrial:
http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/convolutional-neural-networks-tutorial-tensorflow/)

Currently for accuracy, in summary, I use :

```
prediction = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(preds, tf.float32))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    t_acc= accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, y: Y_test})
```

Along with t_acc, how to calculate Spearman and Pearson correlations. Specifically something like this would be fine:

```
 rho, _ = scipy.stats.spearmanr(preds, actuals)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Pearson correlation function in `tf.contrib` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_pearson_correlation)), so you could use:

```
pearson_r = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(prediction, y)
```

Alternatively, you can use `tf.nn.moments` to calculate variance/covariance and compute the metrics by hand.